# Cordova Plugin Firebase GoogleService failed to initialize

Tags: cordova, firebase, analytics, firebase-analytics

I did every step as said and I got this error:

```
GoogleService failed to initialize, status: 10, Missing google app id value from from string resources with name google_app_id.
```

My google-service.json is located in the right place:

[image: My google-service.json is located in the right place]

The hook works, but I still got the error and can't use Firebase plugin:

[image: But I still got the error and cant user firebase plugin]

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 0):

Make sure your widget in config.xml has the id set to the "package name", which should have been defined when you added your project to the Firebase Console.

For example:

```
  <widget id="com.yourappdomain.app" ...>
```

Comment: and where is example?